# TypeError: Cannot read property "tbody" from undefined

Tags: google-app-engine, xml-parsing, google-apps-script, html-parsing

I am trying to parse the html in google apps script, the xPath of the element in HTML is :

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[8]
```

How do I access it in the script? I tried the following :

```
var doc = Xml.parse(responseText, true);
var number = doc.html.body.table.tbody.tr.td
                .table.tbody.tr[1].td.table.tbody
                .tr[3].td.table.tbody.tr.td.table
                .tbody.tr.td[2].table.tbody.tr[2]
                .td.table.tbody.tr[2].td[2].table
                .tbody.tr[2].td[1].table[2].tbody
                .tr[3].td[1];
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xPath itself was wrong, the tbody was added by firefox. So check the path in IE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a hierarchy of elements that you treating as a single chain.
Please post the xml string `responseText` instead of this "xPath" so you and we can see it more clear. Please also specify on the xml the element you're trying to fetch.

When you update your question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The responseText is a HTML code which is very long, how do I attach it here?

Comment: well, you can do it on pastebin.com or paste just the relevant part. Is this xml public accessible? I mean, can I fetch it myself?

Comment: the xPath itself was wrong, the tbody was added by firefox. Thanks all.